# For what values of $a$ and $b$ does the series $\sum_{n\geq1}\ln^{a}(n)n^{b}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to know for what values of $a,b$, the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln^a(n) n^b$ converges. I have some specific cases, but I couldn't determinate anything in a general way. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Since $\ln(n) < n$, you can try to apply the comparison test to $n^{a + b}$.

Comment: "For what values ..."  Including complex values?

Comment: There aren't very many textbooks about number series *not* covering that one. Did you really consider *any* specific case?

Comment: The post [When does $\sum_{n=2}^\infty n^\alpha (\log n)^\beta$ converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14040/when-does-sum-n-2-infty-n-alpha-log-n-beta-converge) contains one really nice answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Considering
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty n^b \ln^a n $$
it's clear that the sum diverges for $b>-1$ and converges for $b < -1$ irrespective of $a$.  In the case $b=-1$ use [Cauchy's condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test):

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty n^{-1} \ln^a n \ \ \text{ converges} 
\quad\iff\quad
 \sum_{n=2}^\infty 2^n\cdot 2^{-n} \ln^a (2^n) \ \ \text{ converges}$$

The sum on the right is
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty 2^n\cdot 2^{-n} \ln^a (2^n)
= \ln^a (2)\cdot \sum_{n=2}^\infty n^a $$
and converges iff $a<-1$.  What's left for you is to show that the preconditions for that test are met, and to work out some details of $b\neq-1$.

Taking all together, the series converges iff $b < -1 \lor (b = -1 \land a < -1)$.